# Any way to disable /wp-login.php redirecting to the site folder?

Tags: security, wp-login-form

We have our WP installs in folders on the server. We created folders called wp-admin and login to thwart hackers. However, incredulously, when you type in /wp-login.php it REDIRECTS to our mysite.com/folder.

I cannot believe WP is making it this easy.

How to disable anyone accessing wp-login.php through the address bar?

Comment: is it a question or a rant? easiest way to disable access to wp-login.php is in htaccess or just create a file named like that.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to block access is in the pre_virtualhost.conf or your equivalent httpd configuration file.

This code will block any access to yourdomain.com/wp-admin and redirect to a blank page with message, "Denied". However, it will not block anyone trying to access yourdomain.com/somefolder/wp-admin.

```
<Location /wp-admin>
order deny,allow
Deny from all
allow from localhost 127.0.0.1 207.58.143.240
ErrorDocument 403 "Denied."
</Location>
```

I would advise familiarizing yourself with mod_rewrite.c, which allows you to set explicit conditions with incredible flexibility.